# Can adobe air send SMS on ios and android without opening the native sms app?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Is it possible to programatically create and send an SMS text message on android and ios using adobe AIR?   I have had success using navigatetourl to create the sms message, but was curious to know if its something that AIR is capable of or if os-specific native development is required to accomplish this.

I'm using flash builder 4.6 and AIR 15.

Answer (score 0):

Can be used ANE library. For example FPMessages.ane (currently supported iOS only): http://flashpress.ru/blog/ane/messages/?lang=en

```
if (FPPhone.canSendText) {
  FPMessages.phone.reinit();
  FPMessages.phone.setBody('body text');
  //
  var r1:String = '88001234567';
  var r2:String = 'UserName from contact list';
  FPMessages.phone.setRecipients([r1, r2]);
  //
  FPMessages.phone.autoHide = true;
  FPMessages.phone.show();
} else {
  trace('sms/mms/iMessage is not supported');
}
```

Comment: hmmm, at first glance it looks sketchy (cant really find any info on others who have used it) is this your own ANE or are you just a user of this ANE?

Comment: It's my ANE, in the process of development, but now everything works without problems. There is also an API for sending email in air app.

Comment: ok, great... .good luck with it.  I'll check it out this weekend!